# How do I extract specific elements from a named list?

Tags: r

```
Gold15 <- read.csv("Gold15.csv")  
colnames(Gold15) <- c("Date", "Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")  
HammerFormed <- NULL  
PrecedingHammer <- NULL  
PostHammer <- NULL  
Profit <- NULL  

for (i in 1:nrow(Gold15)){  
  FULLBODY <- Gold15[i,"High"] - Gold15[i,"Low"]  
  LOWERSHADOW <- Gold15[i, "Open"] - Gold15[i, "Low"]  
  UPPERSHADOW <- Gold15[i, "High"] - Gold15[i, "Close"]  
  CANDLEBODY <- Gold15[i, "Close"] - Gold15[i, "Open"]  


  if (FULLBODY >= 3*CANDLEBODY && UPPERSHADOW <= 0.05*FULLBODY && LOWERSHADOW >= 0.6*FULLBODY){  
HammerFormed <<- c(HammerFormed, Gold15[i,c("Date","Time", "Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"]))  
PrecedingHammer <<- c(PrecedingHammer, Gold15[i-4,c("Date","Time", "Open","High","Low","Close","Volume")])  
PostHammer <<- c(PostHammer, Gold15[i+4, c("Date","Time", "Open","High","Low","Close","Volume")])  
Profit <<- c(Profit, (PostHammer$Close - HammerFormed$Close))
  }

}
```

So in this code, PrecedingHammer & PostHammer are named lists. However, when i try to access the elements of these two by using

```
PostHammer$Close[2]
```

or `PostHammer[[6]][2]`

the console returns an NA.
Here is the str() of PostHammer for analysis:`str(PostHammer)
List of 462
 $ Date  : Factor w/ 142 levels "2014.10.13","2014.10.14",..: 5
 $ Time  : Factor w/ 96 levels "00:00","00:15",..: 57
 $ Open  : num 1239
 $ High  : num 1239
 $ Low   : num 1239
 $ Close : num 1239
 $ Volume: int 4254`

Can anyone please tell me how to access the elements of this list?

EDIT: I've uploaded the file Gold15.csv here : [Gold15.csv](http://www86.zippyshare.com/v/z87m0cqQ/file.html)

[github link here](https://github.com/AshishKool/Gold15-stackoverflow)

Comment: It's highly preferable if you use reproducible data (it's a pain, I know, and we end up telling new users this very commonly so don't feel bad). Could you type `data()` to see a list of built-in datasets which you could use to show your problem in a reproducible way or upload and link `Gold15.csv` or provide its contents via `dput`?

Comment: why are you trying to get the second element when there is only one?

Comment: There are 66 elements to each of the names
@Hack-R I've uploaded the Gold15.csv file so hopefully you'll be able to reproduce the problem!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Seems your `for` loop throws some errors, but I think I can fix it.

Comment: As @rawr was getting at, it seems that some of the objects' dimensions are not what you intended due to the way the `for` and `if` is set up. I'll see if I can make it as you intended.

Comment: The file is at one of those websites that deliver browser hijackers.

Comment: @BondedDust Great..... yea, I didn't like the ad but *&*(#&# I didn't need a browser hijacker LOL.  Ashish -- I know that wasn't intentional, but next time if you need to provide a file via an outside link consider GitHub ;)

Comment: really sorry about the site, I didn't know about the browser hijackers and ads. Will use github in the future, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code was resulting in objects having dimensions that you clearly didn't intend and the 2 objects of interest were coming out as very long lists (and not nested in a way that might be useful).

Instead of have an element of your objects called `Closed` with more than one value in those objects for instance, you had a separate single-value list element for every iteration, like `Close`, `Close.2`, `Close.3`, etc.

```
> Gold15           <- read.csv("Gold15.csv")  
> colnames(Gold15) <- c("Date", "Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")  
> HammerFormed     <- data.frame(matrix(nrow= nrow(Gold15), ncol = 7))  
> PrecedingHammer  <- data.frame(matrix(nrow= 1, ncol = 7))    
> PostHammer       <- data.frame(matrix(nrow= 1, ncol = 7))    
> Profit           <- data.frame(matrix(nrow= nrow(Gold15), ncol = 1))    
> 
> for (i in 1:nrow(Gold15)){  
+   FULLBODY[i]    <- Gold15[i,"High"]   - Gold15[i,"Low"]  
+   LOWERSHADOW[i] <- Gold15[i, "Open"]  - Gold15[i, "Low"]  
+   UPPERSHADOW[i] <- Gold15[i, "High"]  - Gold15[i, "Close"]  
+   CANDLEBODY[i]  <- Gold15[i, "Close"] - Gold15[i, "Open"]  
+ }  
> 
> condition <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(FULLBODY), data = 0))
> for(i in 1: length(FULLBODY)){
+   if(FULLBODY[i] >= 3*CANDLEBODY[i] && UPPERSHADOW[i] <= 
+        0.05*FULLBODY[i] && LOWERSHADOW[i] >= 0.6*FULLBODY[i])
+   {
+     condition[i,1] <- 1
+   }
+ }
> table(condition) 
condition
    0     1 
10714    66 
> 
> HammerFormed    <- Gold15[condition[,1],]
> 
> for(i in 1:nrow(condition)){
+   if(condition[i,1] == 1){
+       PrecedingHammer[i,] <- Gold15[i-4, ] 
+     }
+ }
> 
> # Remove NA's
> PrecedingHammer <- PrecedingHammer[!(is.na(PrecedingHammer[,1])),]
> 
> for(i in 1:nrow(condition)){
+   if(condition[i,1] == 1){
+     PostHammer[i,] <- Gold15[i-4, ] 
+   }
+ }
> 
> # Remove NA's
> PostHammer <- PostHammer[!(is.na(PostHammer[,1])),]
> 
> names(PostHammer) <- colnames(Gold15)
> PostHammer$Close[2]
[1] 1242.96
>
```

At a high level what I did was:

1. Worked with dataframes not lists, which are more flexible and allow me to easily create objects with the dimensions you were expecting
   1b. Initialized your objects to more appropriate dimensions and classes
2. Created an index indicating which rows of the data met your criterion, to avoid loops which could leave gaps or otherwise break
3. Broke it apart into smaller steps to make sure we know what's going on and eliminate mistakes
4. Seeing that the lag/lead logic was necessarily going to result some rows of all `NA` values subsequently got rid of those rows

Comment: It's gonna take me a while to understand what you've done, but it works, so thank you very much!